# How to grey-out area outside of a Polygon?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a Polygon on a Map which serve as "Area of Interest", how do I "grey-out" the area outside of the Polygon? (highlighted in pink)

[image]

Here's my codes:

```
require(["esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/Graphic"], function (
  Map,
  MapView,
  Graphic
) {
  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets-navigation-vector"
    //basemap: "hybrid"
  });
  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-118.80500,34.02700],
    zoom: 13
  });
  var polygon = {
    type: "polygon",
    rings: [
      [-118.818984489994, 34.0137559967283],
      [-118.806796597377, 34.0215816298725],
      [-118.791432890735, 34.0163883241613],
      [-118.79596686535, 34.008564864635],
      [-118.808558110679, 34.0035027131376]
    ]
  };
  var simpleFillSymbol = {
    type: "simple-line",  // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
    color: "darkblue",
    width: "2px",
    style: "long-dash"
  };
  var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
    geometry: polygon,
    symbol: simpleFillSymbol
  });

  view.graphics.add(polylineGraphic);
});
```

**Update:**
I end up using a custom layer and create a mask using the Polygon.
https://codepen.io/kwokhou/pen/YzGwLOb?editors=0010

Comment: another option (with a lot less custom code) is to use the blending effect, see example at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/blendmode-multiple-layers/index.html and more details on https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#blendMode

Comment: @BjornSvensson Thanks. That does looks good!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would calculate the spatial [difference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#difference) between the area of interest and view extent, and display it as greyed-out. Something like this:

```
var polygon = new Polygon({
    rings: [
        [-118.818984489994, 34.0137559967283],
        [-118.806796597377, 34.0215816298725],
        [-118.791432890735, 34.0163883241613],
        [-118.79596686535, 34.008564864635],
        [-118.808558110679, 34.0035027131376]
    ]
});
 
var polygonFillSymbol = {
    type: "simple-fill",
    color: new Color([128, 128, 128, 0.5]),
};

var polygonGraphic;

watchUtils.whenTrue(view, "stationary", function () {

    if (view.extent) {

        var screen = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(Polygon.fromExtent(view.extent));
        var polygonsDiff = geometryEngine.difference(screen, polygon);

        if (polygonGraphic !== undefined) {
            view.graphics.remove(polygonGraphic);
        }

        polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
            geometry: polygonsDiff,
            symbol: polygonFillSymbol
        });

        view.graphics.add(polygonGraphic);          
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. But the "grey-out" are needs to be re-calculated every time  user pan or zoom out the map, so there's a delay when showing the grey-out area. Is there a way to grey-out the entire map instead of just the view extent?

Comment: I was thinking about this when I was writing the answer yesterday, but I haven't come up with anything so far.

Comment: I end up using a custom layer and a mask for the Polygon. The code more complex but it's much smoother. You can see it here https://codepen.io/kwokhou/pen/YzGwLOb?editors=0010. Your idea leads me to finding that solution, so thanks.

Comment: Is there no "inverted polygon" equivalent in Esri software? In QGIS you just select "inverted polygon" style and set it to a grayish fill with blending mode to gray everything under the layer out. It doesn't need to be calculated, it is just as fast as a normal fill style. And it works the same on QGIS Server as on Desktop (and mobile).

Comment: @KlasKarlsson this is for the JavaScript api, running on web browser.

Comment: Yes, @KlasKarlsson, the API supports blendMode - see example at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/blendmode-multiple-layers/index.html or API reference at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#blendMode